# Ask for password when a user wants to delete a file or folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to know how to prompt a user to enter a password when he tries to delete a folder in linux based OS.

Comment: Please be more specific: Who owns the directory? One specific only or any directory? Is it shared between people?

Comment: Root user owns the directory. It is not shared between people. I want a user prompt when we try to delete the folder. This prompt should appear if we try to delete from GUI or command line.

Comment: And which password should be asked for? That of the user who tries to delete (as a check against sessions left open), or that of the `root` user, or one specific to the directory or file that is to be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Since the directory is owned by root and it is one specific directory only, the simplest approach would be setting an immutable flag. As `root`, do:

```
chattr +i directory
```

That way the directory may not be renamed, moved, nor deleted. If you want to delete it, you manually have to remove the attribute.

```
chattr -i directory
```

Not a prompt per se, but it makes you take extra steps before removal.

Comment: Are there any apps available which asks for a prompt when we try to delete?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. It's not very trivial to implement this.

Comment: @adirajuuttej As the directory is owned by root (and so should be its parent), no GUI environment should allow you to delete it without elevating yourself in the first place. I hope that you are not just running GUIs as root or passwordless admins.